# Multiple Instances of Python on C Drive - Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I just tried to install a new instance of python on my C drive under a new directory, and I received a warning that my existing python instance would be replaced.  Under what condition will this occur?  How do I prevent this and allow them not to affect each other?

For instance, I have the following installations:

- C:\Anaconda2\Python.exe
- C:\Python27\Python.exe
- C:\NewDir\NewDir\Python.exe

I received the error message when trying to install the last item on the list above.  I know most responses are going to ask why on God's green earth I would configure my python instances this way, but for now, I'm trying to better understand the conflict.  So please focus on that and not the design of the installations/ environment.  I'm working with some legacy installs I need to clean up.

Comment: can you supply the warning message itself?

Comment: @Some1Else i bypassed the msg and completed the installation.  I cannot seem to recreate it without uninstalling and reinstalling which I cant do at the moment.  The msg basically said that my existing python installation would be replaced.

Comment: the new instance of python you're trying to install is the same as Python27 or it's another version of python?

Comment: @Some1Else the old version of python was a 27 version, but the new installation is a newer verison, 2.7.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. So basically the new installer will create new associations for .py and .pyw. When you'll double click - the new version will be executed. Also it could change your PATH environment variable thus changing the default python.exe you'll execute when you use cmd or other indirect method of calling "general python".

As long as you call specifically python.exe from the folder itself, there should be no problem.

Comment: what do you mean by new associations?

Comment: When you click on a file, for example a .zip file, there is a default program that executes it(for me, winrar). So the same thing, for python.

Comment: I see, thank you.  As long as these are the only changes implied in the warning then i think i'm good.